# How to launch an other ps1 within a ps1 with an other accompt (and admin rights)?

Tags: powershell, runas, admin-rights

I've got a bug on some of my users computers and I need my users to launch a .ps1 from their computer to fix the problem so i can access to their computer when they need it through NetSupport.
Problem is that they don't have administrator rights on their computer.

So this is what I did already :

- Encrypt an admin password in a .txt (this one will be launch by me with administrative rights)

```
    Function RandomKey {
    $RKey = @()
    For ($i=1; $i -le 16; $i++) {
    [Byte]$RByte = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 256
    $RKey += $RByte
    }
    $RKey
}
$Key = RandomKey

$key |Out-File "$path\Key.txt"

Read-Host "Enter one admin Password" -assecurestring | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key $Key | Out-file "$path\EncKey.txt"
```

This part seems to work fine.
Now, come the working "client" part :

```
$PassKey = get-content "$Path\Key.txt"
$Password = get-content "$Path\EncKey.txt" | Convertto-SecureString -Key $PassKey
$User = Read-Host "Enter the ID given by your administrator"
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Pscredential `
-Argumentlist $User,$Password
```

And the not working one (I tried a lot of things here some exemple) :

- 1 : When I set the local administrator (.\administrator) a new powershell Windows start with administrator rights but doesn't do what the file.ps1 is supposed to do, and if I set domain\adminaccount it just start a new posershell windows but without admin rights.

```
Start-Process powershell -Credential $credentials -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-file "\\serveur\path\file.ps1" "}'
```

- 2 : When I set the local administrator (.\administrator) a new powershell Windows start with administrator rights but only half of the script (file.ps1) works, and if I set domain\adminaccount : same as above.

```
Invoke-Item (Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credentials ((Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName) + "\\serveur\path\file.ps1" ))
```

- 3 and so on

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-executionpolicy, bypass, -file "\\serveur\path\file.ps1", -Credential $credentials, -verb RunAs'

Start-Process -filepath "\\serveur\path\file.ps1" -Credential $credentials -ArgumentList '-noprofile -noexit -command  -verb runas}'

Start-Process powershell -Credential $credentials -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-file "\\serveur\path\file.ps1" "}'
```

But nothing works as expected...
If you guys have an idea it'll be wonderfull !!

--------------------- EDIT ----------------
I did a mistake in my file.ps1, so

```
Invoke-Item (Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credentials ((Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName) + "\\serveur\path\file.ps1" ))
```

This work fine with local admin (.\administrator), the script does start with admin rights and works as expected.
BUT... it doesn't work with domaine admin (domain\admin) : the script does start, but without admin rights...

Comment: `set-executionpolicy remotesigned` may help

Comment: Thanks for your answer but where could I use it ? Because you need administrator rights to modify executionpolicy, and that's all the point, being able from an account with no administrator rights to restart powershell using encrypted credentials and as administrator (i'm pretty sure some of few exemple I've wrote may restart powershell with my admin account but not with admin rights...

Not sure if I'm clear on what I'm trying to do... :/

Comment: If you're looking to create a situation that allows non-admins to connect and perform admin tasks, then you might want to take a look at [contrained endpoints](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/introduction-to-powershell-endpoints/).

Comment: Thx Boxdog, but I think remote command need Netlogon service to be started on the remote computer.
Sadly this is the problem i'm trying to fix : here my file.ps1 :
```Powershell
Set-Service -name Netlogon -StartupType Automatic -Status Running

Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public -Enabled False
```

Comment: Oh wow ! I just read again what I just wrote and I noticed that I've made a mistake in the firewall part : 
```Powershell
 Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public -Enabled False
```
It's suppose to be Domain and Private, nor public ! That's why I thought point '2' was half working !

Well so it works with local admin (.\administrator)... but any idea to make it work with a domain account administrator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone interested by the solution I found to make it work with local administrator account  here it is :

Couldn't make it work with the file.ps1 I wanted to execute on a UNC path.
So I had to copy it 1st on the local computer executing the script.

```
$path="[...]\temp"
$source= "[...]file.ps1"
$destination = "c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents"
if (!(Test-Path "$destination\Netlogon_Firewall.ps1")){Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination}
```

Then I import my credentials :

```
$PassKey = get-content "$Path\Key.txt"
$Password = get-content "$Path\EncKey.txt" | Convertto-SecureString -Key $PassKey
$User = Read-Host "Enter the ID given by your administrator"
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Pscredential `
-Argumentlist $User,$Password
```

And finaly i can start the file.ps1 script with administrator rights :

```
Start-Process -Credential $Credentials "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME" -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass & '$destination\file.ps1'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using this [script](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SecurityFever/1.0.2/Content/Functions%5CInvoke-Elevated.ps1) ?

I was able to call this as below and get an elevated session.

```
Invoke-Elevated -FilePath \\server\share\file.ps1
```

Comment: Seems promessing but I'm not sure of how to use it as it needs administrator rights to works, and the point is I need to use encrypted $credentials to RunAs "DomainAdmin" the file.ps1  :
   " .DESCRIPTION
   [...]
    It's important, the command does use the current user context. This means,
    the current user needs administrative permissions on the local system.
    If no file path or script block is specified, the current running process
    will be run as administrator."

Comment: @"Karthik SN" : if this can help you for an other time, this is how I'm restarting a powershell file when I've got admin rights on the computer (so you just have to execute the file and it'll restart with admin rights) :
```Powershell
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)){ Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, My bad in not considering credential into account.
Thanks for sharing the script.

Comment: It's ok, thanks for trying to help me ;) 
A pleasure if it can be usefull.